# Entropy depletion in /dev/random on Beaglebone

Tags: security, hardware, linux

I have a Beagleblone Black with an ARMv7 SoC. `/proc/cpuinfo` says the hardware is *`Generic AM33XX`*. It is running Debian and the 4.1.15-ti-rt-r40 kernel.

I run a lot of stress tests as part of my testing regime. The Beagleboard is suffering entropy depletion in `/dev/random`. In blocking mode it takes minutes to read a handful of bytes. For example, it took 646 seconds to generate 10 bytes.

The machine has `rng-tools` installed, which usually keeps `/dev/random` in good working order. Or it does so on other Debian platforms like including my CubieTruck and Wandboard. I guess the entropy daemon has some trouble on this platform.

The question is kind of broad because I am not sure of the approach. I don't know if I should be using another package to ensure entropy, or if I need another program or driver. Or maybe something else.

My question is, how can I keep `/dev/random` in good working order on the Beaglebone?

---

Dmesg shows a hardware random number generator:

```
[21.308396] omap_rng 48310000.rng: OMAP Random Number Generator ver. 20
```

And the kernel was configured to provide the driver as a module:

```
$ cat /boot/config-4.1.15-ti-rt-r40 | grep HW_RANDOM_OMAP
CONFIG_HW_RANDOM_OMAP=m
```

---

```
$ uname -a
Linux beaglebone 4.1.15-ti-rt-r40 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Thu Jan 7 23:32:08 UTC 2016armv7l GNU/Linux

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 996.14
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x3
CPU part        : 0xc08
CPU revision    : 2

Hardware        : Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as this is really a generic Linux/Unix question. It would probably be better asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: also are you 100% sure that the rng-tools daemon is running?

Comment: yes, but is `rngd` running?

Answer (score 3):

The local work-around for me was run `rng-tools` directly from `rc.local`:

```
$ cat /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

if [ -e /usr/sbin/rngd ]; then
    /usr/sbin/rngd -r /dev/hwrng -f
fi

exit 0
```

A bug was also filed against Debian: [Issue 911043, rng-tools does not perform as expected on Beaglebone Black with OMAP hw rng](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=911043).

I'm going to leave the question open in case anyone knows the real fix for the `systemd` problems.

---

The statement in @MariusMatutiae's answer at [How can I run a command after boot?](https://superuser.com/q/685471/173513) was very true:

> In [the systemd] case, you should learn how to start a service to be
>   run by systemctl, but this may be more than you bargained for with
>   your simple question.

I've wasted over 4 hours trying to get this working using `systemd` methods and controls. I guess I should not feel bad since the distro could not get it to work.